# How do I retrieve repeated species names when using gnr_resolve in R? (taxize)

Tags: r

I have a csv file of ~3000 species records, and I know that some of the latin names for these species have typos or are spelled incorrectly. I want to use taxize/gnr_resolve in R to ouput a list of corrected/matched species names, and replace the existing list of latin names with the corrected list, fixing the typos.

My dataframe is called GWspecies2, and is a list of ~3000 species names.

The issue is that gnr_resolve returns only one entry per species name, and drops repeated entries. So, when I try and export the output of corrected/matched species names to a csv, I am only getting ~1000 entries of the unique species names that appear in the dataset.

```
temp <- gnr_resolve(GWspecies2, best_match_only = TRUE, canonical = TRUE)
temp
species3 <- temp$matched_name2 #this gets me only a list of ~1000 species names
```

[R console output of running gnr_resolve on dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOWwO.png)

As you can see, there are only ~1000 entries here and each line has a unique species name. However, in my original dataset, there are 21 entries for Acer campestre, for example. I would like a gnr_resolve output that keeps these repeats and returns my full ~3000 rows of corrected species names.

I think I've looked fairly extensively online and cannot find a resolution to efficiently recover the repeated species in the correct order, or have gnr_resolve return a row for every entry in the dataframe.

Comment: You can `dplyr::left_join` or `merge` the `temp` data frame with `GWspecies2`.